# How to iterate an image texture and save the iteration with python

Tags: python, scripting, image, uv-image-editor

What I have so far is this, and of course doesn't work yet.

```
import bpy

class TestSaver(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Save Image Increment"""
    bl_idname = "image.save_increment"
    bl_label = "Save Image Increment"
    bl_options = { 'REGISTER', 'UNDO' }

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        original_type = bpy.context.area.type
        bpy.context.area.type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR'
        #bpy.ops.image.save_as(copy=True)
        bpy.ops.image.save_as(save_as_render=False, copy=True,
                             filepath="test_save2.png", 
                             relative_path=True, 
                             show_multiview=False, use_multiview=False)
        bpy.context.area.type = 'FILE_BROWSER'
        bpy.ops.file.filenum(increment=2)
        bpy.context.area.type = original_type

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Please expand your question with an explanation of how this image changes (what mechanism?).  Without knowing what is going on here, I'd think that you need to just put the texture on a mesh that fills the camera and then render the animation to get all the copies of the texture as it varies over time.

Comment: I intend on saving the current state while painting on the image as a new image iteration in the same filepath, similar to when one manually presses 'save image as' and then presses the + to add 1 to the end of the filename, and again the +1 becomes a 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you compute your filepath using a function like this:

```
from os.path import isfile

def next_file_name(pattern):
    i=1

    if (pattern%1) == (pattern %2):
        raise Exception("bad file name pattern")

    while isfile(pattern%i):
        i=i+1
    return pattern%i

print ( next_file_name("/var/tmp/blender/voronoi-wave/%04d.png") )
```

( thanks, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/check-whether-a-file-exists-using-python )